# Modify search result page

Tags: search

I'm using drupal 7 and i'm having some problems customizing the search results page. I have a form altered in template.php file where i have created my fields like this:

```
$form['basic']['keys']['search_string'] = array
      (
        '#prefix' => '<div class="search_title">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#type'=>'textfield',
      )
```

I also created a page search-results.tpl.php where i just wrote:

```
 dprint_r($search_results)
```

When i submit the form i get on /search/node and another form is displayed with the following error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: keys in search_form_validate() (line 145 ..)Please enter some keywords.
```